# Apple Sign-in - Validating ID Token

Tags: c#, jwt, openid-connect, apple-sign-in

I am implementing Apple Sign-in in Mobile app. After successful sign-in, I get the ID token which is valid for one day.

Here is sample JWT token which I received after sign-in:

```
eyJraWQiOiJZdXlYb1kiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FwcGxlaWQuYXBwbGUuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiY29tLmNsdWJiYWJsZSIsImV4cCI6MTYxODU4NTcyOCwiaWF0IjoxNjE4NDk5MzI4LCJzdWIiOiIwMDE4NTAuMzdkY2NmZGIxYzEyNDliY2E2NjE5YThkYjQ2MWFlNDkuMDQzMyIsImNfaGFzaCI6InVMTUV1eTRCaFozRVc1NXR1OXZtZGciLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE2MTg0OTkzMjgsIm5vbmNlX3N1cHBvcnRlZCI6dHJ1ZX0.e86uz4Qqu63mD0hHVdzBU3EfW0G-rDUprBiXkyPkvPIHIWPM1LyjpFs2GeoWAcdfUdmGww6C8SLLgk4iMKjK_yrpxiQBmbIzdCLBrwW4P8Y40llcrotyRuwyalfycyUJ8GP9yqjs5_R7yZlDd4oq0wrDNyXVjlbdGSfNUGqmXScBgXm3yCH0rD85GK0hX3XM-fA133Y5tj1DRALZhnw2GLy-6YEPBlqFE-cvu9aif9ajuDx3gPwp9AQ_nXP3pWjSg2G5eYx7UMpowXbAVoDSlhQVu_KJgxPsW61i50QnhykmeNA7LxA2iLQnlGk5VKzNlATub49SybUnmPSViO_Fbw
```

Now I want to validate this token using `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` available under `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`.

I wrote following code:

```
tokenHandler.ValidateToken(body.access_token, new TokenValidationParameters() 
{ 
    ValidateIssuer = true,
    ValidIssuers = new List<string> { appleTokenIssuerName },
    ValidateAudience = true,
    ValidAudiences =  new List<string> { appleAppClientId },
    ValidateLifetime = false,
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    IssuerSigningKey = // I want to pass signing key here but I'm not sure how can I do that.
}, out SecurityToken token);
```

Apple signing keys are available as Json web key set here - https://appleid.apple.com/auth/keys

Can you help me find correct way to supply this key to `SecurityKey` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use `JsonWebKey` and pass to the constructor a JSON with one of the keys. A more elegant way would be to create a resolver, which could download those keys from Apple when needed. This will also enable you to create fallbacks and refresh keys from Apple when they rotate.

Comment: Can you help with some code sample or reference material I can look into?

Answer (score 1):

[`IssuerSigningKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.tokenvalidationparameters.issuersigningkey) expects an object derived from [`SecurityKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.securitykey). Examples of this are [`JsonWebKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.jsonwebkey) or [`RsaSecurityKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.rsasecuritykey).

Since the posted link contains public keys in JWK format, `JsonWebKey` (as already mentioned in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67121749/9014097)) is a close solution:

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
...
string jwkSerialized = @"{
                        ""kty"":""RSA"",
                        ""kid"":""YuyXoY"",
                        ""use"":""sig"",
                        ""alg"":""RS256"",
                        ""n"":""1JiU4l3YCeT4o0gVmxGTEK1IXR-Ghdg5Bzka12tzmtdCxU00ChH66aV-4HRBjF1t95IsaeHeDFRgmF0lJbTDTqa6_VZo2hc0zTiUAsGLacN6slePvDcR1IMucQGtPP5tGhIbU-HKabsKOFdD4VQ5PCXifjpN9R-1qOR571BxCAl4u1kUUIePAAJcBcqGRFSI_I1j_jbN3gflK_8ZNmgnPrXA0kZXzj1I7ZHgekGbZoxmDrzYm2zmja1MsE5A_JX7itBYnlR41LOtvLRCNtw7K3EFlbfB6hkPL-Swk5XNGbWZdTROmaTNzJhV-lWT0gGm6V1qWAK2qOZoIDa_3Ud0Gw"",
                        ""e"":""AQAB""
                        }";
JsonWebKey jwk = new JsonWebKey(jwkSerialized);
```

The key matching the posted JWT can be identified by the *kid* contained in the header of the JWT, e.g. using https://jwt.io/.

As said before, the import is not limited to the JWK format. E.g. if the key is in the widely used X.509/SPKI format, it can be imported (e.g. under .NET Core 3.0+) as follows:

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
...
byte[] x509der = Convert.FromBase64String("MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA1JiU4l3YCeT4o0gVmxGTEK1IXR+Ghdg5Bzka12tzmtdCxU00ChH66aV+4HRBjF1t95IsaeHeDFRgmF0lJbTDTqa6/VZo2hc0zTiUAsGLacN6slePvDcR1IMucQGtPP5tGhIbU+HKabsKOFdD4VQ5PCXifjpN9R+1qOR571BxCAl4u1kUUIePAAJcBcqGRFSI/I1j/jbN3gflK/8ZNmgnPrXA0kZXzj1I7ZHgekGbZoxmDrzYm2zmja1MsE5A/JX7itBYnlR41LOtvLRCNtw7K3EFlbfB6hkPL+Swk5XNGbWZdTROmaTNzJhV+lWT0gGm6V1qWAK2qOZoIDa/3Ud0GwIDAQAB");
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsa.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(x509der, out _); 
RsaSecurityKey rsask = new RsaSecurityKey(rsa);
```

The equivalence of both keys can be verified e.g. [here](https://8gwifi.org/jwkconvertfunctions.jsp).

The posted JWT can then be verified as follows using either `jwk` or `rsask`:

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
...
bool verified = false;
string jwt = "eyJraWQiOiJZdXlYb1kiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FwcGxlaWQuYXBwbGUuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiY29tLmNsdWJiYWJsZSIsImV4cCI6MTYxODU4NTcyOCwiaWF0IjoxNjE4NDk5MzI4LCJzdWIiOiIwMDE4NTAuMzdkY2NmZGIxYzEyNDliY2E2NjE5YThkYjQ2MWFlNDkuMDQzMyIsImNfaGFzaCI6InVMTUV1eTRCaFozRVc1NXR1OXZtZGciLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE2MTg0OTkzMjgsIm5vbmNlX3N1cHBvcnRlZCI6dHJ1ZX0.e86uz4Qqu63mD0hHVdzBU3EfW0G-rDUprBiXkyPkvPIHIWPM1LyjpFs2GeoWAcdfUdmGww6C8SLLgk4iMKjK_yrpxiQBmbIzdCLBrwW4P8Y40llcrotyRuwyalfycyUJ8GP9yqjs5_R7yZlDd4oq0wrDNyXVjlbdGSfNUGqmXScBgXm3yCH0rD85GK0hX3XM-fA133Y5tj1DRALZhnw2GLy-6YEPBlqFE-cvu9aif9ajuDx3gPwp9AQ_nXP3pWjSg2G5eYx7UMpowXbAVoDSlhQVu_KJgxPsW61i50QnhykmeNA7LxA2iLQnlGk5VKzNlATub49SybUnmPSViO_Fbw";
var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
try
{
    tokenHandler.ValidateToken(
        jwt,
        new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuers = new List<string> { "https://appleid.apple.com" },
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudiences = new List<string> { "com.clubbable" },
            ValidateLifetime = false,
            IssuerSigningKey = jwk // alternatively, rsask can be used            
        },
        out SecurityToken token);
    verified = true;
    Console.WriteLine("Token: " + token.ToString());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Verification failure: " + ex.Message);
}

Console.WriteLine("Verified: " + verified);
```

Comment: `'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.JsonWebKey' to 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityKey'` is the error I get when I tried your solution!

Comment: I'm using `.NET Framework v4.8`, `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens v5.3.0`, `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt v4.0.3.308261200`

I'm working on Azure Mobile app project `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Authentication` has dependency on `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt (> 4.0.3 && < 5.0.0)`

Comment: You should post such info in the question from start, especially when such old versions are involved (the current version of `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` is v6.10.2). On my machine, the code is successfully executable under .NET Framework 4.8 down to `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens v5.3.0` and `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt v5.0.0`. Anything below `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt v5.0.0` doesn't compile (_CS0246: ... 'JwtSecurityTokenHandler' could not be found_). It's possible that this is different under Azure. This seems to be an issue of your specific environment/configuration.